# Django : python manage.py runserver (multiple errors)

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, ubuntu

I started using Django recently for my first web app following a tutorial on youtube, every thing went fine until this command : `$ python manage.py runserver` meaning i was able to create a virtual environment and create a project using : `$ python3 -m django startproject <projectname>`.

Here's what my **manage.py** looks like:

```
"""Django's command-line utility for administrative tasks."""
import os
import sys


def main():
    """Run administrative tasks."""
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'django_blog.settings')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        )
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here are some of my different attempts and errors:

`$ python manage.py runserver`
Error:

```
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 14, in main
    "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

Attempt n°1:

`$ python pip install django` Error:
`python: can't open file 'pip': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`
`$ python -m pip install gekko` Still gives the same error as above after `$ python pip install django`

Attempt n°2:

`$ python3 manage.py runserver` and `$ python3.6 manage.py runserver` both gives the same error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
from _sqlite3 import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_sqlite3'
```

Tried using:
`$ pip3 install pysqlite3` 
`$ sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev` then inside
`~/Downloads/Python-3.6.2$ ./configure --enable-loadable-sqlite-extension && make && sudo make install`

still the problem persisted.

Attempt n°3:

`$ python3.5 manage.py runserver`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 11, in main
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named 'django'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 14, in main
    "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

This is the most recent error:

```
from django.urls import path
ImportError: cannot import name path
```

Here is my urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Here is what i get when i run the `sudo tree` command on linux

```
thalagalage@3n1gm4:~/chamika/Python/DjangoBlog$ sudo tree
.
├── django_blog
│   ├── django_blog
│   │   ├── asgi.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __init__.pyc
│   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   │   ├── settings.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   │   └── urls.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── settings.py
│   │   ├── settings.pyc
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   ├── urls.pyc
│   │   └── wsgi.py
│   ├── manage.py
│   └── manage.sublime-workspace
└── django_env
    ├── bin
    │   ├── activate
    │   ├── activate.csh
    │   ├── activate.fish
    │   ├── activate.ps1
    │   ├── activate_this.py
    │   ├── activate.xsh
    │   ├── django-admin
    │   ├── django-admin.py
    │   ├── easy_install
    │   ├── easy_install3
    │   ├── easy_install-3.6
    │   ├── easy_install3.6
    │   ├── pip
    │   ├── pip3
    │   ├── pip-3.6
    │   ├── pip3.6
    │   ├── __pycache__
    │   │   └── django-admin.cpython-36.pyc
    │   ├── python -> /usr/bin/python3
    │   ├── python3 -> python
    │   ├── python3.6 -> python
    │   ├── sqlformat
    │   ├── wheel
    │   ├── wheel3
    │   ├── wheel-3.6
    │   └── wheel3.6
```

Below are the step by step commands i use in order to get in to my virtual environment, until i get stuck with the `manage.py runserver` command which throws the `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_sqlite3'`.

```
thalagalage@3n1gm4:~/chamika/Python/DjangoBlog$ ll
total 16
drwxr-xr-x  4 thalagalage thalagalage 4096 sept.  5 19:02 ./
drwxrwxr-x 11 thalagalage thalagalage 4096 sept.  5 18:13 ../
drwxr-xr-x  3 thalagalage thalagalage 4096 sept.  5 19:32 django_blog/
drwxr-xr-x  4 thalagalage thalagalage 4096 sept.  5 18:03 django_env/
thalagalage@3n1gm4:~/chamika/Python/DjangoBlog$ source django_env/bin/activate
(django_env) thalagalage@3n1gm4:~/chamika/Python/DjangoBlog$ python3 -m django --version
3.1.1
(django_env) thalagalage@3n1gm4:~/chamika/Python/DjangoBlog$ cd django_blog
(django_env) thalagalage@3n1gm4:~/chamika/Python/DjangoBlog/django_blog$ ll
total 32
drwxr-xr-x 3 thalagalage thalagalage  4096 sept.  5 19:32 ./
drwxr-xr-x 4 thalagalage thalagalage  4096 sept.  5 19:02 ../
drwxr-xr-x 3 thalagalage thalagalage  4096 sept.  6 01:02 django_blog/
(django_env) thalagalage@3n1gm4:~/chamika/Python/DjangoBlog/django_blog$ python3 manage.py runserver
```

**Thank you for your help!**

Comment: You don't install package with `python pip`, but with `pip`, so `pip install django`, not `python pip install django`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you should do is to create a virtual environment. Virtual environment is a place where your packages would be placed, For example Django is one of the modules. In order to create a virtual environment you have multiple choices like `pipenv`, `virtualenv`, etc.

### A) Virtualenv

1. You can install `virtualenv` using the following command:

```
pip3 install virtualenv
```

2. Create a new virtualenv. The common virtualenv names are `venv`, `env`, etc.

```
virtualenv --python=python3 --no-site-package <virtualenv-name>
#example:
virtualenv --python=python3 --no-site-package venv
```

3. Activate the virtualenv. In current directory open terminal (in linux and Mac OSX) or powershell (in windows) and execute the following command:

```
source <virtualenv-name>/bin/activate
```

4. Install the packages you want. The name of your virtualenv should be prepended to the shell in paranthesis.

```
(<virtualenv-name>) pip3 install django
```

5. Finally run the server successfully.

```
(<virtualenv-name>) python3 manage.py runserver
```

### B) Pipenv

1. Installing pipenv.

```
pip3 install pipenv
```

or in linux you can execute the following lines:

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pypa/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install pipenv
```

2. To create new environment using `pipenv` you have to enter the following line in your terminal.

```
pipenv --python 3.6
```

3. Install the packages you need.

```
pipenv install django
```

4. Run the server.

```
python3 manage.py runserver
```

**PS:** If you still have the problem running the project, it's better to create a new project from scratch:

1. Create a new virtualenv as described above.
2. Activate the virtualenv.
3. Install Django.

```
(venv) pip3 install django
```

4. Create new django project.

```
(venv) django-admin startproject <project-name>
```

5. Change directory to the django project directory and then run the server.

```
(venv) cd <project-name>
(venv) python3 manage.py makemigrations
(venv) python3 manage.py migrate
(venv) python3 manage.py runserver
```

Comment: I followed your instructions step by step yet, i got the same ModuleNotFoundError:         `File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
 from _sqlite3 import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_sqlite3'`

Comment: Do you use virtualenv or pipenv? After activating the virtualenv try executing `which pip` in terminal? what is the output of it?

Comment: Both gave me `pipenv : command not found`, when i execute `which pip` it gives me `/usr/bin/pip`

Comment: Sorry you should enter whiich pip3

Comment: Do you activate the virtualenv? I have updated my answer. I recommend to do the sequence again.

Comment: I have updated my thread to show all the commands i used until reaching the `ModuleNotFoundError`, do you think maybe the error occurs because i have two files with the same name `/django_blog`?

Comment: No, they must have the same name. it's the default behavior of Django. I think the problem is with the version of your python. Let's start a new project and then test it. I have added the instruction to my post. take a look.

Comment: I really appreciate your help throughout this thread. **Thank You**, just as you said i started a new project and `(venv) python3 manage.py migrate` was a gamechanger, thanks again.

Comment: Ofcourse, right now i only have 13 "reputation" as soon as i get 15, i'll make sure to give you an up vote. ;)

Answer (score 1):

maybe use a venv like pipenv for your project

`pip3 install pipenv`

`pipenv install django` install the necessary packages u want to use

`pipenv shell` to activate the venv

`py manage.py runserver`

Comment: The first command works fine but after using `pipenv install django` it says `pipenv: command not found`

Comment: oh i think u might need to use pip3